# Unable to save view: "There is already an object named 'Quotes' in the database." - Error 1222

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I often get the aloof error message above, after trying change a view in SQL Managment Studio 2008.  I right-click on a view, select 'design', make a change (or not), and click the Save button.

It only happens on some Views.  Others save instantly.  I also can't delete or rename this View, and instead get the error "lock request timeout period exceeded...  ..@objname is ambiguous or claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong."  Can I remove this lock, assuming that really is the problem?

Is there a way to fix, or get around this bug in SSMS?  It's happening more and more, maybe because my queries are getting larger?  I don't know.

**Edit:** After more reasearch I see this bug is identified by the 1222 error, and [MSDN has directions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337412.aspx) for a workaround, which states:

"Use sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks and sys.dm_tran_locks dynamic management views"

Currently I'm trying to figure out what "Use sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks" really means.

Comment: I just had this error today. I realized it was happening because I had a solution running in visual studio that was using my view. Could that be your issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

"Use sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks" means to run queries against that object to see what's causing the timeouts that you are getting.

Comment: There is no mention of how to identify the process.  sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks has 22 records, so I do not know which one I'm supposed to kill.  Should I just terminate all of them?